# passing parameter in nsurlconnection Post method

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection, uipickerview

[image: screenshot for my coding]I tired picker view with array of four element from url link "branch_name"

(1) with button action.

Button action:

```
- (IBAction)picker_button:(id)sender {
    NSString *parseURL =@"url(1)";
    NSString *encodeurl =[parseURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodeurl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if(data){
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];
        arrMsg = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.branch_name"];
        NSLog(@"%@",json);
        arrmsg1 =[json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.id"];
               [_pickerdata1 reloadAllComponents];
        }

}
```

Then I used url link(2) passing parameter using POST `NSURLConnection` and successfully displayed in tableview.

Post method coding:
here i am passing parameter as Branchid=@"1" only but i want to pass parameter as entire branchid value. help me

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method{
    NSString *Branchid =@"1" ;

    NSURL *url = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    if([method isEqualToString:@"GET"]){

        NSString *getURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?branch_id=%@", URL, Branchid];
        url = [NSURL URLWithString: getURL];
        request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSLog(@"%@",getURL);

    }else{  // POST

        NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@",Branchid];
        NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL];
        NSLog(@"%@", parameterData);
        request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setHTTPBody:parameterData];

        arr= [NSMutableString stringWithUTF8String:[parameterData bytes]];
        }

    [request setHTTPMethod:method];
    [request addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( connection )
    {
        mutableData = [NSMutableData new];
    }

}
```

connection did finish loading:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError* error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                             error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    sellArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.sell"];
    buyArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.buy"];
    updataedArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.updated"];
    imageArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.flag_image"];
    currency =[json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.currency"];
    [ _dataview reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: your question looks more like write code for me requirement. Please explain properly where you are stuck and include only relevant code for it. No need to add hundreds of lines of code to the question

Comment: Why do you have 5 returns in the numberOfRowsInSection method ? Only the first one is executed so this method will return always sellArray.count

Comment: i stuck in while passing parameter in post method @Shubhank

Comment: then re edit the question and only show code related to post method

Comment: here i used 2 url link from (1)st url using picker view from that i get "id" as parameter that can pass through (2)nd url link using POST method@Shubhank